# incompatible pointer types passing nsstring to parameter of type const char (error)

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers, libxl

***I am using core data and libxl. Whenever i implement a Core Data string into libxl it gives me the error "incompatible pointer types passing nsstring to parameter of type const char"***

Dont know why...

**Here is my code, namelabel.text is the core data NSString that produces the error incompatible pointer types passing nsstring to parameter of type const char.**

```
- (IBAction)createExcel:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"createExcel");

    BookHandle book = xlCreateBook(); // use xlCreateXMLBook() for working with xlsx files

    SheetHandle sheet = xlBookAddSheet(book, "Sheet1", NULL);

    xlSheetWriteStr(sheet, 1, 1, namelabel.text, 0);
    xlSheetWriteNum(sheet, 4, 1, 1000, 0);
    xlSheetWriteNum(sheet, 5, 1, 2000, 0);

    FontHandle font = xlBookAddFont(book, 0);
    xlFontSetColor(font, COLOR_RED);
    xlFontSetBold(font, true);
    FormatHandle boldFormat = xlBookAddFormat(book, 0);
    xlFormatSetFont(boldFormat, font);
    xlSheetWriteFormula(sheet, 6, 1, "SUM(B5:B6)", boldFormat);

    FormatHandle dateFormat = xlBookAddFormat(book, 0);
    xlFormatSetNumFormat(dateFormat, NUMFORMAT_DATE);
    xlSheetWriteNum(sheet, 8, 1, xlBookDatePack(book, 2011, 7, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0), dateFormat);

    xlSheetSetCol(sheet, 1, 1, 12, 0, 0);

    NSString *documentPath =
    [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filename = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"insuranceclaim.xls"];

    xlBookSave(book, [filename UTF8String]);

    xlBookRelease(book);

    if (![MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
        //Show alert that device cannot send email, this is because an email account     hasn't been setup.
    }

    else {

        //**EDIT HERE**
        //Use this to retrieve your recently saved file

        NSString *documentPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *filename = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"insuranceclaim.xls"];

        //**END OF EDIT**

        NSString *mimeType = @"application/vnd.ms-excel"; //This should be the MIME type for els files. May want to double check.
        NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filename];
        NSString *fileNameWithExtension = @"insuranceclaim.xls"; //This is what you want the file to be called on the email along with it's extension:

        //If you want to then delete the file:
        NSError *error;
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filename error:&error])
            NSLog(@"ERROR REMOVING FILE: %@", [error localizedDescription]);


        //Send email
        MFMailComposeViewController *mailMessage = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        [mailMessage setMailComposeDelegate:self];
        [mailMessage addAttachmentData:fileData mimeType:mimeType fileName:fileNameWithExtension];
        [self presentViewController:mailMessage animated:YES completion:nil];
    }


}


- (void)mailComposeControllerone:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error {

    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Mail cancelled: you cancelled the operation and no email message was queued.");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            NSLog(@"Mail saved: you saved the email message in the drafts folder.");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"Mail send: the email message is queued in the outbox. It is ready to send.");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"Mail failed: the email message was not saved or queued, possibly due to an error.");
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"Mail not sent.");
            break;
    }

    [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

@end
```

Comment: Might I suggest setting a few break-points and pin-pointing _where_ your code is failing? That way you can just post the relevant code instead of the unnecessarily large amount of code you've posted above. Nobody wants to sift through all of that to debug your code for you.

Comment: Ok, I've only posted the relevant code.

Comment: And the error doesn't identify the problem statement??

Comment: Yes it does... the problem is the error. namelabel.text in libxl is the problem.

Comment: It would help if you pointed out the line of code causing the problem instead of posting a lot of irrelevant code.

Comment: -1 for not identifying the failing line.

Comment: BTW - the error tells you the exact problem. You are trying to pass an `NSString *` value to a parameter of type `const char *`. You need to convert your `NSString` to ` const char *`.

Comment: @Stonz2 - The code never even compiled.  He's quoting a compiler error message.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To convert to `const char *` try

```
const char *s = [namelabel.text UTF8String];
```

and pass it wherever you need to.

**Edit**:

```
xlSheetWriteStr(sheet, 1, 1, [namelabel.text UTF8String], 0);
```